# Remove html class using CSS

Tags: html, css, dom

I want to remove HTML elements classes using CSS. What is the method of removing classes from HTML using CSS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**You can't remove classes with CSS** because that's for **styling** only and it can't modify the DOM. **JavaScript** hover, is able to do that. You could use this snippet to achieve that:

```js
const classesToRemove = ['class1', 'class2', 'class3'];

const removeClassesFromElements = () => {
    classesToRemove.forEach((className) => {
        let elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

        for (let element of elements) {
            element.classList.remove(className);
        }
    });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    removeClassesFromElements();
});
```

```html
<h1 class="class1"></h1>
<p class="class2"></p>
<hr class="class3" />
```

Answer (score 4):

CSS cannot modify the classes applied in the DOM and is used only for visual styling.
To change classes of an element you have to use JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You can't. **CSS** is *`Cascading Style Sheets`* and is used **only** for styling, read more about CSS in [this w3chools article](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_css.asp).
For changing *element's class* you need to use **`Javascript`**, there are a bunch of methods to do this and most famous of them are `pureJS DOM` methods which you can learn [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) and of course amazing [JQuery](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-dom.htm#:%7E:text=JQuery%20provides%20methods%20to%20manipulate,from%20a%20paragraph%20or%20division.), both are not very hard and convenient but I prefer JQuery myself

Answer (score -1):

CSS can't modify any HTML elements. But You can use pseudo classes for certain triggers.
Use :focus or :hover. Also you can use checked state of a hidden checkbox like

```css
checkbox:checked + .btn {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6b15ce;
}
```